# firebase ios gooffline remove observers

Tags: firebase

Simple question:

Will all obersvers automatically removed when I use goOffline (disconnect to firebase) ?

If not, is there another way to do it, because removeAllOberserves doesn't seem to work or must I keep an array of single handles?

UPDATE

I answer myself.
removeAllOberserves works well, if you call it with the reference you used to set the observer!

Example:

```
Firebase *userThreadRef;

userThreadRef = [userRef appendPathComponent: ThreadsPath]; 
[userThreadRef observeEventType: FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock: ^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
...
}];

....

[userThreadRef removeAllObservers];
```

Do not use a new reference like this:

```
Firebase *newUserThreadRef = [userRef appendPathComponent: ThreadsPath]; 
[newUserThreadRef removeAllObservers];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will all observers automatically removed when I use goOffline (disconnect to firebase) ?

No. Calling `goOffline()` will not automatically remove observers/listeners.

> is there another way to do it, because removeAllOberserves doesn't seem to work or must I keep an array of single handles?

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but likely your expectations are just wrong.

You'll need to call `removeAllObservers()` on each reference. The `All` in the method name is for the fact that it removes the observers for all event types, not for all references.